# Управление программно созданными компонентами

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Программно динамично (пользователь сам создаёт) создаются условные кнопки и тексты.

Как им программно присваивать id, чтобы потом конкретно созданной кнопкой можно было и дальше совершать операции (пользователь может создать неограниченное количество компонентов)?

Answer (score 1):

Например, нам нужно нам нужно создать программно неопределённое количество кнопок. Во-первых, создаём в `Activity` список, в котором будем сохранять `Button`:

```
private List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Добавлять поля мы в будем в `LinearLayout`. Определим его там же в `Activity`:

```
private List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();
LinearLayout layout;
```

И инициализируем в `onCreate`:

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

Создадим метод `addButton` для добавления на экран нового `Button`:

```
public void addButton() {
    Button button = new Button(this);  // создаём новый Button
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);  //  Указывает размеры
    button.setId(buttonList.size());  //  Устанавливаем id (индекс в списке)
    button.setText("Не нажата кнопка №" + (buttonList.size() + 1));
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  // Устанавливаем слушателя
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = v.getId();  //  Получаем id (индекс в списке)
            Button button = buttonList.get(position);  //  Получаем кнопку
            button.setText("Нажата кнопка №" + (position + 1));  // Как-нибудь это обрабатываем
        }
    });
    buttonList.add(button);  //  Добавляем в список
    layout.addView(button);  // Показываем на экран
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у вас есть `button`, который создан программно.

Тогда, грубо говоря, есть 2 способа:

1) Самый правильный:

```
//работает только с API 17
button.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

2) Немножко самопальный, но все равно правильный - написать самому этот генератор (вернее взять его из исходников):

```
public class ViewIdGenerator {
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int generateViewId() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
            for (;;) {
                final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
                // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
                int newValue = result + 1;
                if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF)
                    newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
                if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return View.generateViewId();
        }

    }
}
```